# Layout and disabled function

Tags: android, layout

This is possible to disabled layout for few seconds? I want to layout shows users but user can click on elements this layout after 5 seconds. This is my idea: I start activity and all components will be showing, but user can click on them after 5 seconds. This is possible?

Comment: This is possible, but it will result in a very bad user experience, users will be thinking that something's going wrong with your application and that it's frozen. Try avoid this kind of behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, easily enough.

I'll give a simple example with code that supports one button. The code below will go in `onCreate` or `onStart` or `onResume`, wherever you prefer. And I am assuming you are setting your layout in `onCreate` before any of the code I have below.

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        button.setOnClickListner(...);
    }
},5000);
```